Power Automate desktopのWebページからデータを抽出するアクションの追加ができない。
色々検索しても解決策が得られなかったため質問します。
Windows 11 Pro
Power automate desktop Version 2.44.46.24141
Google chrome 125.0.6422.142 64bit
上記すべて最新版で使用しております。
新しいChromeを起動するでインスタンスを作成し、Webページからデータを抽出するというアクションを追加しました。ライブWebへ流パーが現れて、実際のページから抽出したいテーブルを選ぼうとしているのですが、以下のエラーが出て次へ進めません。どこを確認したら良いでしょう？
ハンドルされないエラー メッセージ＝メソッドが見つかりません
System.String.Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.UIAutomation.WebAutomation.Core.Browser.WebHelperBrowserExtensions.HighlightAndExtractRecordsAsStringifiedJSon

拡張機能のアンインストール、再インストールやPAD自体の再インストール、Edge、Firefoxへの変更は試してみました。
よろしくお願いいたします。
